# Application Error (app crash in heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just deployed an updated version of my code into heroku but I'm getting this error. It was working fine locally so I thought it was safe. Anyone know what went wrong? 
In terms of new gems, I installed twitter and oauth gems. I got rid of them just now, but still getting the same app crash.

Here's the heroku log

```
C:\Users\app5>heroku restart
Restarting processes... done



    C:\Users\app5>heroku logs
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.421854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.421854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.421854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
7:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422084+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422320+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2013-04-09T03:34:10.422542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:11.642431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-09T03:34:11.659334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret
 option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         provide a secret to prevent
 exploits that may be possible from crafted
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         cookies. This will not be s
upported in future versions of Rack, and
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         This poses a security threa
t. It is strongly recommended that you
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         future versions will even i
nvalidate your existing user cookies.
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bu
ndle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abs
tract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:
2013-04-09T03:34:12.186269+00:00 app[web.2]:
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249332+00:00 app[web.2]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249332+00:00 app[web.2]: => Rails 3.2.3 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:24777
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249516+00:00 app[web.2]: Exiting
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249948+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250053+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249332+00:00 app[web.2]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249766+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/controllers/comments_contr
oller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class CommentsControll
er (TypeError)
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250225+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_o
r_load'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250140+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250419+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on
'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249332+00:00 app[web.2]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250629+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa
d!'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250717+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250804+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.250889+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.251036+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.251210+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.249861+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252214+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.251418+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.251294+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253756+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254594+00:00 app[web.2]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'

2013-04-09T03:34:16.250509+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_d
ependency'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252784+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in
require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253016+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253420+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252874+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_depe
ndency'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253243+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252657+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253333+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254035+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253588+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254207+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254509+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252302+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252402+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.251126+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253672+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252571+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
7:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.252488+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253116+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253875+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.253504+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254123+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254292+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254376+00:00 app[web.2]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-04-09T03:34:16.254842+00:00 app[web.2]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-04-09T03:34:17.704246+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-09T03:34:17.719603+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-04-09T03:35:06.060820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=appname.com fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno= connect= service
= status=503 bytes=
```

Gemfile.lock file

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activeadmin (0.5.1)
      arbre (>= 1.0.1)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (>= 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (>= 1.3.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
    activemodel (3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.3)
      activemodel (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
    activesupport (3.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.8)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
    bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.5)
      will_paginate
    bourbon (3.1.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      thor
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
    cucumber (1.2.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.11.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2)
      cucumber (>= 1.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.0)
    database_cleaner (0.7.0)
    devise (2.2.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    excon (0.13.4)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.3.2)
      activesupport
    factory_girl_rails (1.4.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.4.0)
    ffi (1.4.0-x86-mingw32)
    fog (1.3.1)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.13.0)
      formatador (~> 0.2.0)
      mime-types
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-scp (~> 1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)
      ruby-hmac
    formatador (0.2.4)
    formtastic (2.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    friendly_id (4.0.9)
    gherkin (2.11.6)
      json (>= 1.7.6)
    gherkin (2.11.6-x86-mingw32)
      json (>= 1.7.6)
    growl (1.0.3)
    guard (1.6.2)
      listen (>= 0.6.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      terminal-table (>= 1.4.3)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (0.5.5)
      guard (>= 0.8.4)
    guard-spork (0.3.2)
      guard (>= 0.8.4)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    httpclient (2.3.3)
    i18n (0.6.4)
    impressionist (1.2.0)
      httpclient (~> 2.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
    inherited_resources (1.3.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.6)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.7)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.1.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    listen (0.7.3)
    lumberjack (1.0.2)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_search (1.1.3)
      actionpack (~> 3.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.1)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.21)
    mini_magick (3.5.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-ssh (2.6.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.6)
    nokogiri (1.5.6-x86-mingw32)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.12.2)
    pg (0.12.2-x86-mingw32)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    pry (0.9.12)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry (0.9.12-x86-mingw32)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      win32console (~> 1.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activerecord (= 3.2.3)
      activeresource (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.3)
    railties (3.2.3)
      actionpack (= 3.2.3)
      activesupport (= 3.2.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.4.3.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.9.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
    rinku (1.7.2)
    rsolr (1.0.8)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec (2.9.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.9.0)
    rspec-core (2.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.9.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
    rspec-rails (2.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.9.0)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.6)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    slop (3.4.3)
    spork (0.9.0)
    spork (0.9.0-x86-mingw32)
      win32-process
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5-x86-mingw32)
    subexec (0.2.2)
    sunspot (2.0.0)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
    sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
      nokogiri
      sunspot (= 2.0.0)
    sunspot_solr (2.0.0)
    terminal-table (1.4.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.4)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.36)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)
    win32-process (0.7.1)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
    win32console (1.3.2-x86-mingw32)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.0.1)
  bootstrap-sass (= 2.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.5)
  capybara (= 1.1.2)
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (= 3.2.2)
  cucumber-rails (= 1.2.1)
  database_cleaner (= 0.7.0)
  factory_girl_rails (= 1.4.0)
  faker (= 1.0.1)
  fog (~> 1.3.1)
  friendly_id
  growl (= 1.0.3)
  guard-rspec (= 0.5.5)
  guard-spork (= 0.3.2)
  impressionist
  jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
  launchy (= 2.1.0)
  meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre)
  mini_magick
  pg (= 0.12.2)
  rails (= 3.2.3)
  rb-fsevent (= 0.4.3.1)
  rinku (~> 1.7.2)
  rspec-rails (= 2.9.0)
  sass-rails (= 3.2.5)
  simple-private-messages (= 0.0.0)!
  spork (= 0.9.0)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
  sunspot_rails
  sunspot_solr
  uglifier (= 1.2.3)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.3)
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this class (CommentsController):  `superclass mismatch for class CommentsController (TypeError)`

Comment: I didn't even touch that file though.. I checked an older version of the CommentsController file and it's the same

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you've redefined a class unintentionally, perhaps by attempting to reopen the class after defining it elsewhere in your app. Try searching your app for `class CommentsController`... if it shows up more than once and it is intended, you'll want to make sure all usages inherit from the same parent class. I assume it should be `class CommentsController < ApplicationController`... in each usage.

Comment: what's the best way to run the search for `Class CommentController`?

Comment: I don't know what your setup is, but if you have MacOSX/Linux, you can run `$ grep -nR 'class CommentsController' .` from the command line root of your project. Another popular search tool is [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/). If you use an IDE, you can probably look for a 'find in project' command.

Comment: I'm on windows... is it possible to run a search from rails console?

Comment: God help you. Short of that, you can google [how to search a directory of files for an expression](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30). You could also try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (or something similar) to emulate a Unix command line tool in Windows which would give you a lot more capability.

Comment: lastly, are there specific folders that I should pay attention to when I do a search? I'm assuming the search should focus on .rb file type?